# Sending a GET request on node.js process exit

Tags: node.js, axios

I would like to send a telegram message by using a GET request before exiting the process.

I tried multiple combinations but none of them worked.

```
process.stdin.resume();

function onExit () {
  axios.get(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${config.telegram.BOT}/sendMessage`, {
    params: {
      chat_id: config.telegram.USER,
      parse_mode: 'markdown',
      text: 'message'
    }
  })
  console.log('Exiting...')
  process.exit()
}

['exit', 'SIGINT', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGUSR2', 'uncaughtException', 'SIGTERM'].forEach((eventType) => {
  process.on(eventType, onExit.bind(null, eventType));
})
```

It ignores the axios request. What am I doing wrong here ? I know it should be synchronous only, but I'm not using any async/await here.

It shows fine the console logs "Exiting..." but that's all

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `axios.get` is async and returns a promise. Try this one:

```js
function onExit () {
  axios.get(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${config.telegram.BOT}/sendMessage`, {
    params: {
      chat_id: config.telegram.USER,
      parse_mode: 'markdown',
      text: 'message'
    }
  })
  .then(_=>process.exit(),_=>process.exit());
  
  console.log('Exiting...')
}
```

Comment: Oh, what an amateur mistake I've made. I've slightly updated your answer to make it work. Thank you

Comment: It's ok. I rolled back. By the way, in your version system will not perform process.exit(..) if promise will be rejected.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work with `.then(_=>process.exit(),_=>process.exit());`, but it works with `.then(() => { process.exit() })` instead